# How can I generate a rest get service with json using jhipster?

Tags: java, json, rest, get, jhipster

The comand `jhipster spring-controller Foo` I can generate a controller wiht a service get, but the generated service is with a string, but I want change this generation with json, how can I do?

Comment: You mean without manually modifying generated code? An alternative would be to use API first, see https://www.jhipster.tech/doing-api-first-development/

Answer (score 1):

Create a pojo or java class, and use it as response, spring boot automatically converts it to json format during transmission of the data

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the command `jhipster entity Foo` instead of `jhipster spring-controller Foo`

With the entity command your pojo will be generated as-well and a controller will be created. This controller will convert the response to json just like you want it.

Personally I'm not a big fan of generating my code with the command-line options, because there is a lot of manual steps to go trough. 
Instead I use a JDL file to define my entities and import that file with the command `jhipster import-jdl nameOfJDLFile.jh`

More info on jdl: https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/options